# SSRS line subgrouping by lines and not by columns

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I want to have a row subgroup that will act like a head line with the details belonging to each subgroup (see below)

[image]

This is what I've done so far

1. Add a parent row group with the field **LibelDestinataire** as you can see in the picture

[image]

2. This is the result I have

[image]

Something is wrong but I'm unsure where. I've used a table. I've tried with a matrix but it did not do what I expected.

Any tips are welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new tablix, right click the details group, select Add Group / Parent Group and use this settings:

[image]

You will get a tablix like this:

[image]

Delete the left most column (created by the group).

[image]

Delete the first row and use the LibelDestinataire field in the selected cell.

[image]

Merge the three cell next to the first cell and set the other fields in the next row:

[image]

You will get something like this:

[image]

In preview it should be something like this:

[image]

Apply the color and formats you want to cells and you will get the desired result.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Hi @alejandro-zuleta, the `add group header` was the only missing. When you know, you know otherwise you keep looking ... in the dark

Comment: @AndyK, it is a common workaround to use dynamic headers in SSRS tablixes/matrixes. Hope it helps you.